# SQL72028 Build error in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, build, sql-server-data-tools

A project in SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) in Visual Studio 2015. When I build this project I continue to get the following error:

> SQL72028: An unexpected exception has occurred in the model storage engine. To continue, disregard the current results and try the operation again. If this issue persists, contact Microsoft support.

No other error information is shown in the Errors window. The Output window just says "build failed".

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to clear this is to close the solution and delete the `.dbmdl` file from the project folder. You may also need to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders.

Then you should be able to reopen the project and build successfully.